# Access rule that permits NTP response

Tags: cisco-ios, ntp

Nagios is used from **HOST1** to check the NTP server on **HOST2**. One of the servers resides in an ACL. The assumption was that

```
ip access-list extended vlanX
 permit udp host HOST1 X Y eq ntp
 deny   ip any any log
!
```

would allow the ntp response, but it results in:

```
re-sending request to peer 0
NTP CRITICAL: No response from NTP server
```

while executing the command on HOST2 works. It seems that the NTP has been blocked. How to allow it in the ACL? Note that the ACL works, as PING from specific hosts have to be explicitly allowed by adding new access rules.

Comment: Which direction (IN or OUT) did you apply it on the interface?  Also, since you are logging denies, what message did you get in the log?

Comment: @Ron both (IN and Out as well). I will check the log.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an inbound ACL then it's all right. But if you have applied same list to outbound traffic to interface, then it will result in dropping NTP responses back to your host. Your outbound ACL should look like

```
ip access-list extended ACL-Out
 permit udp X Y eq 123 host HOST1
 deny ip any any log
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a reflexive ACL, which will allow the response packet to go through.

```
permit udp hosta hostb eq <port> reflect
```